Delete particles in Geometry Nodes based on their position during simulation
I'm working on a project where I need to simulate particles using Blender's old particle system. After the simulation is cached, I want to select a few particles based on their position and delete them from the entire simulation.
To achieve this, I've created a test file with a simple particle simulation where I load the particles into Geometry Nodes using the ParticleInstance node. The particles are created on an object with a single vertex.
The challenge:
I need to delete particles that exceed a certain X position (for example, greater than 3 units) at frame 100 of the simulation.
What I’ve tried:
I’ve attempted using Capture Attribute and Store Named Attribute nodes, but these methods only worked on a per-frame basis, deleting particles in real-time when they met the conditions, rather than for the entire simulation.
Bonus question:
Is ParticleInstance the only method to edit traditional particles in Geometry Nodes, or are there other approaches?
Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!


For the bonus question: Geometry Nodes can only modify these types of geometry: meshes, curves, point clouds, volumes and instances. No traditional particles from a particle simulation. So I guess the Particle Instance is the only method. But a stupid question: if you want to get rid of "normal" particles that reach a certain X position: why not place a large collision object there that kills particles, eventually to do this at or after frame 100? Or is it mandatory to do this in Geometry Nodes?

@kiwiblending There is no difference between real-time and per-frame basis. I think you are misunderstanding something about that.

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks! Killing particles in one frame by a collision object will distract the viewer in the animation. Maybe I'll write a little more clearly what the project looks like. I have a pool of balls simulated by the Molecular+ addon, through which various 3D models will pass. Sometimes it happens that a particle sticks to the model, it is not always possible to control it during the simulation. That is why I was wondering if it is possible to mark the indexes of these particles, e.g. at the end of the simulation and remove them completely in the entire timeline.

@Lutzi Thanks for the answer. Yes, there is no difference between real-time and per-frame deletion. I must have written it incorrectly, sorry. If I have 10 particles and 3 of them during 100 simulation frames exceed position 3 in the X axis, I would like to delete them for the entire simulation. So that after the deletion process there are only 7 particles in the first frame. This way I will avoid troublesome simulation moments and I will not have to delete them in real time.

Of course if a condition is first met on frame 100, a Capture Attribute or something similar cannot store the information on frames 1 to 99, because the animation is not running backwards. I guess there is no easy way to do this, you would basically have to read the positions of all particles on frame 100 while you are still on frame 1 and delete all by index which will meet the kill condition on frame 100. So if someone knows a way how to access location data of frame 100 on frame 1, this might help - but I'm not that someone.

Maybe I need to duplicate the object with particles, apply simulation in a given frame and then transfer this information to geometry nodes tree removing the particles? Will try it later.
